# How can I start my application from a sub folder created under wwwroot azure app services

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have deployed my Node.js application its deployed in azure app services
the problem is I can't read it from wwwroot/build
all my node.js files are located inside the build folder
I want that Azure app service start from build folder

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question, but possibly a solution to the root problem you might be having, so to speak. If you specify the folder to deploy using the instructions [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Customizing-deployments#deploying-a-specific-aspnet-or-aspnet-core-project-file), either in a `.deployment` file or in App Settings, the application in your `build` folder will deploy to ``wwwroot`. Then your App Service will start as normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read files from sub folder created under wwwroot in azure app services
go to your azure portal home click on app services then select your app service application
then go to configuration and path mapping, you can set whatever folder you want to start from here.

Answer (score 2):

You can configure it using Virtual Directory

Go to `portal > demo-site App Service > Configuration > Path Mappings > Virtual applications and directories`. And add the following

[image]